# powershell task in task scheduler cannot start-process with another -Credential

Tags: windows-7, powershell, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler, credentials

We have a scheduled task that is a powershell script.  The script performs a number of actions against SQL data-bases where the access is controlled via integrated security.  Hence each of these actions must be performed by a process that is executing under the appropriate Windows AD credentials, and there is more than one set of credentials that must be used.

Details:

The powershell task is invoked in the task scheduler as follows:

```
cmd.exe /C ""powershell.exe" -Noninteractive "C:\someDir\SomeScript.ps1" >"C:\logDir\SomeScript.log" 2>&1"
```

In other words, `cmd.exe` is the `Program/script` invoked, the remainder of the line is the `Add arguments (optional):` part.  (We invoke this way for reasons irrelevant to the question at hand, part of which is the way we have architected logging in the script libraries we have developed.).

In the scheduled task settings (`General`), we select `Run whether user is logged in or not` and `Run with highest privileges`.  The userID running the task, lets call it `ad\admin1`, has local admin privileges.

Within the script `SomeScript.ps1`, we invoke other scripts under different credentials, via

```
Start-Process $explicitPowershellExe -NonInteractive -Credential $credential -Wait -ArgumentList @( '-file', $scriptForSqlOperations )
```

The credentials `$credential` are for users different from `ad\admin1`. This invocation silently fails to start powershell, though no error is generated.  The only clue that powershell fails to start is an event in the "windows Logs"=>System:

Application popup: powershell.exe - Application Error : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.

Note that we can run the script no problem when run outside of a scheduled task.  Running the script `SomeScript.ps1` in a logon session for user `ad\admin1` succeeds any way we run it.  For example, in a `cmd.exe` console (running with admin), we can run the *exact* line

```
cmd.exe /C ""powershell.exe" -Noninteractive "C:\someDir\SomeScript.ps1" >"C:\logDir\SomeScript.log" 2>&1"
```

and it succeeds, or we can more simply run

```
powershell -Noninteractive "C:\someDir\SomeScript.ps1"
```

at the command prompt and all goes well.  So the issue is clearly with something in the way TaskScheduler sets up the `cmd.exe` processes it runs.

Does anyone know what the issue might be and how to get around it? I am suspecting it is some security restriction on impersonation withing a scheduled task????

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure each user you are trying to execute as has the “logon as a batch job” right.

1. Open `gpedit.msc` and navigate to `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment`
2. Add each user to the `Log on as a batch job` right.
3. Run `gpupdate`
4. Try your task again.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/log-on-as-a-batch-job

Comment: users all have admin, and other scheduled tasks run under the other credentials, so it's not a rights issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the key setting preventing the ability to execute `start-process` with other credentials from a scheduled task (where account rights are not the issue) is `"Run whether user is logged on or not".`  Using the `"Run only when user is logged on"` setting does work, but this is of course a problem if you are not logged into the system running the job at the time.  Also, I cannot say if this restriction is limited to the `start-process` command.  Other Windows PS commands allow credentials to be passed as well, but like yourself I have not had success with start-process without using the alternative setting. I have not found a definitive explanation for this limitation.

Comment: Ouch.  Thanks for this confirmation.  (I think we have also found things work with `Run only when user is logged on`, but as you say, this is a problem because we need the process to run whether the account is logged on or not.)  If you find a solution or more information, please come back and post here.  Thanks again.

Comment: I don't recall establishing an appropriate solution to this issue.  I did not look into MS Power Automate for some kind of Remote Desktop automation, for a way to schedule a login to the server so that the scheduled job could run, but one would think there could be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also PowerShell to give Grant “Log on as a service” rights.

This can be archived by using The Script that is published on Microsoft script center here :
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grant-Log-on-as-a-service-11a50893#content

```
.”.\Add Account To LogonAsService.ps1″ “DOMAIN\Account”
```

Replace “DOMAIN\Account” with the name of the account you want to add to the policy.

Check the source here for more info: https://www.get-itsolutions.com/log-on-as-batch-job-rights/

thnx

Comment: All accounts have local admin rights.  I may try this, but I would think LAR trumps this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find a solution to this?

I'm trying to do the same thing - from a scheduled, start other processes as a different account.  The account running the scheduled task, as well as the account used to start the other processes, are in the local Administrators group on the server.

I got around the problem by creating another scheduled task and then running that.  Instead of using start-process with a credential object, my script, started as scheduled task, would create a new scheduled task with no trigger, the action to run is another script and the new task runs as the other user account.  Then it would run the new scheduled task and when it finishes, remove the scheduled task.

The action run by the new scheduled task first creates a file with process details so the original script can track that it's running and get other details as necessary.

It's a bit of 'Rube Goldberg' solution but it works.

Comment: Arrrggg. lol. Good for you for finding a "work-around", but what a nightmare.  No, we never found a solution. The answer from bigguitar above outlines the "work-around" we had to use.